How do I run pi-hole using Podman?
I am building a home server just for fun and for the learning experience. This is my first time, so I am relatively new to all of this. The plan is to run things like pi-hole and Nextcloud and a few other things.
For that, I decided to try to run everything inside its own Podman container on my alma linux server. At first, I tried to install everything directly on the server, but then I got into trouble because multiple services wanted to use the same port (after I found out what all these things are ;) ), and then I read about Podman and thought that might solve my problems.
I followed a tutorial online and installed pi-hole via
podman run -d --name pihole -e TZ="Europe/Zurich" -e WEBPASSWORD="********"  -p 192.168.0.188:5300:53/tcp -p 192.168.0.188:5300:53/udp -p 192.168.0.188:8000:80 -v "/srv/pi-hole:/root:z" --restart=on-failure pihole/pihole:latest

I can then access pihole via 192.168.0.188:8000/admin from my browser. But now I am stuck, because I don't know how to connect for example my phone to it. My router does not allow using my own dns, so I figured that I had to connect all my devices by myself to the pihole.
I can do this if I just install the pi-hole directly on my server (go to settings and put my server ip there), but I don't know how to do this when I install it in the podman container (putting server ip in settings does not work).
Does anybody know how I can solve this?
Ps: This is my first time using such a forum, so please give me your feedback on whether I use it correctly. Thanks
Solved:
I maped the 53 udp/tcp from the server directly to 53 inside of the container. Now everything works fine.

Welcome to the site, and congratulations on finding the solution youself. However, please don't edit your question to contain the answer - write your own answer instead.
